# Want to select multiple text in AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am developing android application. In it i have used AutoCompleteTextview. It works fine in my application when i want to select only one text but what if i want to select multiple text??? After selecting one text it don't get any more suggestion.Plz solve my problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want [`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html). `AutoCompleteTextView` is for single-selection only.